# Unable to add attendees to google calendar using service account

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm having couple of issues with adding attendees to my calendar using google calendar API and service account.
My service account has domain-wide delegation ticket in the cloud console and I am able to create/update a event without adding attendees.

When I try to send request with attendee then I get following response:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority. [403]
Errors [Message[Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbiddenForServiceAccounts] Domain[calendar]
```

This is how my code looks like:

```cs
var eventDetails = _calendarService.GetEvent(eventDto.EventId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
eventDetails.Attendees.Add( new EventAttendee 
   {
      DisplayName = "Test Name",
      Email = "testemail@example.com" // I tried with few emails but results is same
   });
_credential = AuthorizeServiceAccount();
_calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
      HttpClientInitializer = _credential,
      ApplicationName = _calendarOptions.AplicationName,
   });
var request = _calendarService.Events.Patch(eventRequest,_calendarOptions.CalendarId, eventId);
var result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
    
public GoogleCredential AuthorizeServiceAccount()
{
    
   var serviceAccountCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
      new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(_calendarOptions.Id) // I'm using service account email here, tried with clientId but same result
      {
         ProjectId = _calendarOptions.ProjectId,
         KeyId = _calendarOptions.KeyId,
         User = _calendarOptions.User, // I tried with email from request or null value - for both same result
         Scopes = _calendarOptions.Scopes, // ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" ],
      }
      .FromPrivateKey(_calendarOptions.Key));
   return GoogleCredential.FromServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredential);
}
```

Can you please help me so I will be able to add attendees to my events? I don't need to send emails to attendees but emails are required in google API. I don't want also to have  G Suite domain account as it's paid.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are using .NET?

Comment: @JoseVasquez yes this is c# .NET

Comment: By looking at the [Calendar API for C#](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/index.html) and since you mentioned that you have domain-wide delegation on. The error shown might be produced by **1) service account trying to access user calendar outside the domain** or **2) IAM & Admin > Service Accounts > Service account status > Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation** is not checked.